# I'm implementing 3Des Encryption Algorithm for Long Numbers in Java

Tags: java, string, 3des

I'm implementing 3Des Encryption Algorithm for a project.

I using this code as example:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/TripleDES.htm

It's working ok, but I need to send and receive String, but i'm making this to save Credit Card Number on the Data Base, so I need to work with Long numbers, not Strings.

It is some possibillity to do that?.

I have to use a especial Key or I have to do some cast to the returned value?
I'm loking for the best, and most correct, solution.

I know, maybe my question is a little silly, but I'm lost.

Thanks for your answers and sorry for my poor english

Comment: why not convert the long to String? `String.valueOf(long)`

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if that is the best, and correct, solutions. Maybe with a special key, the Algorithm returns allways a long number. Thanks for your answer, that's my "B plan"

Comment: You are misleading us: you are not in fact implementing anything. You are just using the standard library to encrypt.

Comment: Sorry Marko Topolnik if I misleading you, maybe my english is not the best, and the topic or the text is not right. But, I think, that is not the most important.

Answer (score 2):

You need `byte[]` for encryption and from long you can generate `byte[]`

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(long value)    
{  
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);  
    return bb.putLong(value).array();  
}  

public long toLong(byte[] bytes) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    buffer.put(bytes);
    return buffer.getLong();
}
```

Use this `byte[]` for encryption and decryption.
Also note that it is really not good to have credit card number as long.

Comment: Yes, maybe that is a solution, but I don't think the best. It's not possible to set something on the Cipher Class, or on the Secret key, to use numbers and recover numbers??. 

Using your idea, if I have a credit card with 16 digits, I have to applied the encription and i will recover a String of 16 chars.

After that, I have to convert the String to a Byte Array.

Then I have to save that Byte Array in a Number column on my Data Base. How?

Comment: The only "good" way to do that, is to convert every one of this bytes to a number of 3 digits (000, 001, 002..010..045..256), using Ascii code for example, and the create a "Monster" number where every 3 digit number is "concatenated" to the other. So I have a 16 x 3 = 78 digits!.

I don't think that this is the best way :(